# jQuery - Fancybox image not oppening from facybox window?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Im loading some content via ajax, and then im firing fancybox to display that content.

**Code for retrieving content**:

```
jQuery('.trigger').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var someid = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "index.php",
            data: "?option=com_content&view=article&id="+someid+"&tmpl=component",
            success: function(data){
                jQuery("#ajax").html(jQuery(".article",jQuery(data)).html());
                jQuery("#ajax").fancybox().trigger('click'); 
            }
        });
    });
```

This code works - it loads some content and display it in fancybox window.

Problem is that that content also have thumbnail image linked to another image which again must be opened in fancybox. But when i click on image, nothing happens.

Everything works ok, except image that should be opened from retrieved content.

However, if i dont display retrieved content in fancybox window, ie just append it to some element, than image will work fine.

Note also, that on another part of same site, where i dont use ajax i have "fancybox in fancybox thing" and everything works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding:

```
jQuery('#ajax a').live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('fancybox')) {
            jQuery.parent().fancybox.close();
        }
    });
```